# Check & match filename extension

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have a filename 'file1.txt'
How to check if a filename has either of these extensions (jpg, txt, mp4)?

If I add 'txt' first then it returns 1 (true)

```
var test = 'file1.txt';
test.substring(test.lastIndexOf(".")+1) === "txt"|"jpg"|"mp4"
```

and if I add 'txt' in the last like this `"jpg"|"mp4"|"txt"` then it returns 0.

I want to simply check that if a filename has any extension or not.

Comment: Put your file name inside quotes.And if you want to use OR condition then you have to check individually.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to do that when writing here.

Comment: did I get -1 for asking duplicate question?

Comment: Not sure who did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `test` here with a regex pattern:

```js
console.log(/\.(txt|jpg|mp4)$/.test('file1.txt'));
```

One coding advantage here to the regex approach is we can just list all extensions we want to match in an alteration.  In your current attempt, we can't compare a string to an alternation with `===`.

Comment: why does (/\.(jpg|mp4|txt)$/.test(test1)) === false  returns false?

Comment: Because the expression evaluates to true?  Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: my apologize, i misunderstood it.